# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://movies.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Hurrah - I am so pleased that the community is going to get a larger set of moderators, and that these will be chosen by the community - which has changed significantly since the beta was launched.

Comment: I totally agree!  And, in the spirit of change, it's time for some new Moderator blood.  By the way, my campaign manager has handed over some photos of iandotkelly at a Yahoo Answers rally that are pretty damning.  So, you know, just be careful who you vote for and what their agenda is...

Answer (score 4):

If I did not read the [data](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/1) wrong, those are the winners of the first M&TV election and our new site moderators:

- [iandotkelly](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40/iandotkelly)
- [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson)
- [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma)

Congratulations and the best of luck in your new position. I am sure you will do a great job representing our community and keeping our site clean!

And also a big thanks to all candidates for putting their hat in the ring and all voters for taking part in the election!

---

Some election facts (errors excepted):

- "905 voters were eligible, 312 visited the site during the election, 323 visited the election page, and 166 voted"
- That means we have a turnout of 18.3%.
- The ranking of the 10 candidates, in order of opposite elimination (so: first to last):

  - iandotkelly
  - Napoleon Wilson
  - Ankit Sharma
  - Trish Ling
  - System Down
  - Paulster2
  - Johnny Bones
  - MattD
  - atticae
  - Vijin Paulraj

Comment: Yes, I absolutely echo the 'big thanks' - everyone that entered is a very valuable member of the community here.

Comment: Quite happy about this, all three are my favorites specially the one with "A" at start :D. Anyways thanks.